# Onchange events for multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, html, function

here's my javascript

```
function disp(s)
    {
        var st=document.getElementById("stats");
        st=st.options[st.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("sp").innerHTML="this is changing :"+s;
        if(st=="Other")
        {
            document.getElementById(s).style.display="inline";
        }
        else
            document.getElementById(s).style.display="none";
    }
```

and here's my front end

```
Rain Guage Status
            <select id="stats" onchange="disp('oth')"><option>
                Good
                    </option>
                    <option>
                        Bad
                    </option>
                    <option>
                        Other
                    </option></select>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter the status briefly" style="display:none" id="oth">
Exposure
            </td>
            <td><select id="expo" onchange="disp('othe')"><option>
                Good
                    </option>
                    <option>
                        Bad
                    </option>
                    <option>
                        Other
                    </option></select>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter the exposure briefly" style="display:none" id="othe">
```

the problem i'm facing is that exposure texbox opens up only when rainguage textbox is displayed... there's no relation to both of dropdowns except for the function which takes the id of textbox to display.
like if rainguage tb is displayed and exposure tb is displayed, i cannot hide exposure tb unless i hide rainguage tb. please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are getting the element by id `stats`. Instead you can pass the element with your function.

```
<select id="stats" onchange="disp(this, 'oth')">
<select id="expo" onchange="disp(this, 'othe')">
```

and Update your function like this :

```
function disp(ele,s)
{
    //var st=document.getElementById("stats"); No need for this line
    var st=ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].text; //use ele from here
    document.getElementById("sp").innerHTML="this is changing :"+s;
    if(st=="Other")
    {
        document.getElementById(s).style.display="inline";
    }
    else
        document.getElementById(s).style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: omg! i'm a total idiot for not checking that!! i'll take this question down.. it's absolutely useless... and btw, why are we passing "this" as an argument? is there any benefits from it? i can just pass the oth and othe and get the job done right?

Comment: You can do that. But sending this will reduce your code / work to get the element. Also you don't need to close the question. We all learn from mistakes here! :)

Comment: except this error is absent mindedness, surely wouldn't appear in someone's code... also i tried your solution and it didn't work.. mostly because "this" doesn't have the id and your st on right side isn't declared...i've put a simple "if" condition to solve my problem!

Comment: That should be ele instead of st. Sorry for that. As I said, we all learn from mistakes here! ;)

Answer (score 0):

**use onchange event for multiple select as follows.**
1.give same class name for all select as below.

```
<select id="stats" class='select-box">
<select id="expo" class='select-box">
```

2.use jquery onchange function

```
$( ".select-box" ).change(function() {
      alert( "option selected" );
   });
```